# Custom Value of Checkbox 'Y'/'N' instead of true/false. Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a data which I want to display in a checkbox.The data has a boolean condition 'Y'/'N'. My problem is checkbox input only accepts true/false. Is there a way to change the value of checkbox that instead of true/false I want it to accepts 'Y'/'N';

Sample Data:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "0.59"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "N"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "value": "LOW"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "HIGH"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "value": "Y"
}]
```

Comment: you could bind the checkbox to a model variable with a settor. When variable is set to true, update another hidden form input value to `Y`. When the variable is set to false, update that hidden input to `N`

Comment: That's what I plan to do at the start but I have a lot of checkboxes which if I think will not be efficient if I implement it. Now I want to create a custom component/ input but still I don't know how to change it to Y and N

Comment: How are you getting your data? From a service via an Observable? You can use .map to convert the Y/N values in the data to true/false when you initially get the data and then bind to the values directly.

Comment: @StephenR.Smith. Yeah it's from a service. Now If I use that can I also do that in post request/saving?. Do you have any sample about mapping the service/changing the value?\

Comment: Can you include a chunk of the json data response in your question so we can see what key/value pairs you're looking at mutating? You can output the data on a component using the json pipe and copy/paste if you don't have a structured data object available. {{ data | json }}

Comment: @StephenR.Smith here it is. [ {
  "id" : 1,
  "value" : "0.59"
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "value" : "N"
}{
  "id" : 3,
  "value" : "LOW"
}, {
  "id" : 4,
  "value" : "HIGH"
},
 {
  "id" : 5,
  "value" : "Y"
}
]

Comment: What I want to change is the value. note that the value field/property is not always boolean. Sometimes it is a string, a number or a boolean. That json is a list which I displayed depending on the value. If it's a number i displayed it using a input[number] , input[text] if s string while checkbox if it's Y/N . That data above is just a portion of the whole data. The actual is a 100 objects with id and value properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this more efficiently, however this is the most clear way to describe the solution to the problem, and it's easy to read / implement / expand on. I've included a link to a plnkr at the bottom which writes the values out to the document so you can see this in action. I've removed the document.write output in the code here:

When you're fetching in your data:

```
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "0.59"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "N"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "value": "LOW"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "HIGH"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "value": "Y"
}]
```

Iterate through the objects in the array, if they are Y or N values, then add a booleanValue key with the appropriate true/false value and bind to that with your checkboxes.

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].value == "Y") {
    data[i].boolValue = true
  } else if (data[i].value == "N") {
    data[i].boolValue = false
  } 
}
```

When you're saving your data (Y / N values removed for visibility, they would still be in your data):

```
const submitData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "0.59"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "boolValue": true
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "value": "LOW"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "value": "HIGH"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "boolValue": false
}]
```

Iterate through the objects in the array, if they are true or false values, then set the value key to the appropriate Y / N value.

```
for (var i=0; i<submitData.length; i++) {
  if (submitData[i].boolValue == true) {
    submitData[i].value = "Y"
  } else if (submitData[i].boolValue == false) {
    submitData[i].value = "N"
  } 
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DrAvyMV5BqADhLdTTn6M?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Stephen. I know it's too much but can I message you outside stackoverflow? I really want to ask more questions. If that's ok . Again Thank you so much :)

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please accept the answer. If you have more questions about this specifically, ask them here so that anyone else with a similar problem in the future can benefit. If you want to talk more about Angular 2, you can find me on the Ultimate Angular Slack Channel, along with a number of other developers. ultimateangular.slack.com

Comment: @Stepehen Thanks a lot. Anyway I would like to join in ultimateangular.slack.com. But it needs to have invitation?