# How to apply an operation to a model property binding?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to apply an operation to a model property binding?  For example, say I have a checkbox control and I'm binding the isChecked to a model's boolean property.  However, I want to invert the value -- true is false and vice versa.

Example of the control I'm working with:

```
<custom-checkbox name="isActive"
                 [(ngModel)]="user.isDeleted"
                 #isActive="ngModel">
</custom-checkbox>
```

In reality, the checkbox represents an 'active' user.  So if the property 'isDeleted' is true then the checkbox is checked which is not correct.  I need to invert the value.

Comment: You mean you need like this `[(ngModel)]="!user.isDeleted"` ?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work.  However, imagine if one needed to change the value to something entirely different.  For example, boolean true/false needs to be converted to string 'yes'/'no'.

Comment: then check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656130/custom-value-of-checkbox-y-n-instead-of-true-false-angular-2

Comment: Thanks.  So, it appears Angular currently has no equivalent to IValueConverter found in Silverlight.

Comment: If you want to do custom things instead of just two way bindings, it's better to split the input to the control `[]=""` and the event output `()=""`. That way you have more control

Comment: Another option is to handle it in the component class with a getter, converting the value as appropriate when the value is retrieved by the template for the binding.